# Is it possible to split CSS grid cell, that was created by merging multiple cells previously?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-grid

Let's say that I have a nested 3x2 CSS grid(`class="main-grid"`) (each cell contains 3x2 grid(`class="item"`) inside). Then I apply the following CSS styling: `.main-grid :first-child {grid-column: 1/3;}`This supposed to merge first two cells of the `main-grid` and do the same for each of `item` grids.

But now I want to split cell/not apply `grid-column: 1/3` styling for just one `item is-special` grid. The cell I want to split is in red (`class="sub-item special"`)

My question is then, how can I split that cell or not apply `grid-column: 1/3` styling to its host `item is-special` grid? (I do no want to make it in another class, as it is important that all the other formatting is uniform with other `item` grids. I also do not want to make another grid inside that cell as a workaround. I've spent a fair amount of time on looking for anything like that on the internet but haven't found anything, so it appears to me as if `grid-column: 1/3` is an irreversible action, which is very strange given that all the other css grid parameters can be overridden, for example `background-color`) **Thus, in short, I am looking for something that will work like so: `.is-special {grid-column: *split*}` or `.main-grid :first-child :not(.is-special){...}`**

Example for reference:

```css
.main-grid{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
border: 1px solid rgb(114, 114, 114);

}
.main-grid :first-child{
  grid-column: 1/3;
  }
.item{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
border: 2px solid rgb(114, 114, 114);
}
.sub-item{
border: 1px solid rgb(114, 114, 114);
}
.special{
background-color: red;
/*How do I split this cell?*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="main-grid">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item is-special">
      <div class="sub-item special">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did tried running your code and **grid-column:1/3** is not applied on `class="sub-item special`, that is only applicable on 1st child of main-grid.

You can implement your css with help of **.item.is-special** selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a more specific selector for your case (see the comment in the CSS)

```css
.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid rgb(114, 114, 114);
}

.main-grid :first-child {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

/* added rule to reset the above one in this special case */
.main-grid .is-special :first-child {
  grid-column: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border: 2px solid rgb(114, 114, 114);
}

.sub-item {
  border: 1px solid rgb(114, 114, 114);
}

.special {
  background-color: red;
  /*How do I split this cell?*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="main-grid">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item is-special">
      <div class="sub-item special">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
      <div class="sub-item">some text</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```